# Simplify Javascript code for form validation

Tags: javascript, forms, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I would like to simplify my Javascript code, is it possibile to not have multiple if conditions? Also, can I have only one swal(sweetalert) and show a custom message for each error?

```
function validare(formElement) {
        var name = document.forms["form"]["echipa"].value;
        var mobile = document.forms["form"]["telefon"].value;
        var email = document.forms["form"]["email"].value;
        var nume = "numele";
        var telefon = "numarul de telefon";
        var telefon_invalid = "un numar de telefon valid";
        var mail = "adresa de email";
        var mail_invalid = "o adresa de mail valida";
        var eroare = 0;
        if (name == "" && name.length < 4) {
            swal('Eroare!', 'Introdu te rog ' + nume, 'error');
            return false;
        }
        if (mobile == "" && mobile.length < 4) {
            swal('Eroare!', 'Introdu te rog ' + telefon, 'error');
            return false;
        } else {
            if (isNaN(mobile) || mobile.length < 8) {
                swal('Eroare!', 'Introdu te rog ' + telefon_invalid, 'error');
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (email == "") {
            swal('Eroare!', 'Introdu te rog ' + mail, 'error');
            return false;
        } else {
            var re = /^(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])$/;
            var x = re.test(email);
            if (!x) {
                swal('Eroare!', 'Introdu te rog ' + mail_invalid, 'error');
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: if `name == ""` than it's length is obviously < 2 ;)

Comment: it's just a condition, I modified it to 4, thanks.

Comment: Even with 4 it is an unnecessary condition, because it always will be true when `name==""`. If you want a length of less than 4 to pass the condition, you need to drop the `name==""` condition.

Comment: You can hardly make this code much simpler. You are doing all the checks you need. You can slightly tweak some lines but overall it's going to be the same. What you can do is break it down into separate parts, each of which is checking for one thing alone. You'll have roughly the same amount of code (maybe very slightly more) but it would be easier to maintain in the future - if you need to change the name validation, you just change that. If you need a new validation, you don't touch the other code. The alternative is to use a validation library which will do most of that for you.

Comment: Same with the other conditions. No need either to have two `if` on `mobile`. There is a lot to be improved on your Boolean logic.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/mruyzafv/embedded/result,js,html,css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
function validare() {
         const echipa = document.forms["form"]["echipa"].value;
         const telefon = document.forms["form"]["telefon"].value;
         const email = document.forms["form"]["email"].value;


  if (!echipa.trim()) {
    showErorMessage('Eroare! Introdu te rog numele');
    return false;
  } else if (!telefon.trim()) {
        showErorMessage('Eroare! Introdu te rog un numar de telefon');
    return false;
    } else if (!validatePhoneNumber(telefon)) {
    showErorMessage('Eroare! Introdu te rog un numar de telefon valid');
    return false;
  } else if (!email.trim()) {
    showErorMessage('Eroare! Introdu te rog o adresa de email');
    return false;
  } else if (!validateEmail(email)) {
        showErorMessage('Eroare! Introdu te rog o adresa de email valida');
    return false;
    }

  return true;
}

function showErorMessage(message) {
    swal('Eroare',message,'error');
}

function validatePhoneNumber(value) {
    return value.match(/\d/g).length === 10;
}

function validateEmail(value) {
    const emailRegex = /^(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])$/;

  return emailRegex.test(value);
}
```